# How to vary browser cache by file type in IIS

Tags: caching, iis, browser-cache, response-headers

Does anyone know how I can declare different values for the browser cache duration in IIS (or web.config) depending on file type?

I would like to (browser) cache my images for a month because they are not going to change, but (browser) cache my css files for a day (for now anyway) as I make several changes to the website over the coming weeks.

I know I can declare Common HTTP Response Headers on a particular folder, which works OK, all be it time consuming... I was hoping I could apply a duration from the top level and site wide for all js files and apply a different duration for css files... Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks in advance